# Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ as a function of $x$ if $\sin y+\cos y=x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

> Find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ as a function of $x$ if $\sin y+\cos y=x$

Ok bit confused as my textbook gives the answer to this problem as:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{(2-x^2)^3}}$$

So I just started in this topic so my methods are kinda basic but what I've done so far is differentiate $\sin y+\cos y=x$ to get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\cos y-\sin y}$$

But I'm not too sure on how to get the second derivative as $\pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{(2-x^2)^3}}$

Any guidance on this one would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating implicitly w.r.t $x$ one time yields $$y' = \frac{1}{\cos y - \sin y}$$

Differentiating this implicitly one more time yields $$y'' = \frac{y'(\sin y + \cos y)}{(\cos y - \sin y)^2} = \frac{\sin y + \cos y}{(\cos y- \sin y)^3} = \cdots$$

---

Combine the above with the fact that $x^2 = 1+2\sin y\cos y \implies 2-x^2 = (\cos y - \sin y)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
We have,
$$(\sin y + \cos y )^2 = x^2$$

$$\sin 2y = x^2 -1 $$

$$ y = \frac{\arcsin (x^2 -1)}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-(\cos y-\sin y)^{-2}(-\sin y-\cos y)\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$=\frac{x}{(\cos y-\sin y)^3}$$

Also $$x^2=1+2\sin y\cos y$$ and $$2-x^2=1-2\sin y\cos y=(\cos y-\sin y)^2$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

set $u=y+\frac{\pi}4$ so $u'=y'$ and $u''=y''$
then, since $\sin(y+\frac{\pi}4)= \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(\sin y + \cos y)$
$$
\sin u = \frac1{\sqrt{2}} x \\
u' \cos u = \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \\
u'' \cos u - (u')^2 \sin u =0
$$
hence:
$$
u'' = \frac{\sin u}{2^{\frac32}\cos^3 u} \\
= \pm \frac{x}{2^{\frac32}(1-\frac{x^2}2)^\frac32} \\
= \pm\frac{x}{(2-x^2)^{\frac32}}
$$